# SceneKit view slows down when presenting another view

Tags: ios8, popover, scenekit

I have a **SCNView which is the main view for the ViewController** in my storyboard. It also has some child views, like buttons.

I set one of these buttons to present a popover. However, **as long as the popover is presented above the SCNView, rendering of the scene is slowed down** (I understand that it's probably to save battery and provide smooth interaction with the popover).

For my application however, this looks pretty bad. I haven't unfortunately found any setting for this. **Is there a way to force the view to render at full speed even when it's partially overlayed?**

I target the iOS version 8.0.

Comment: If the popover is transparent, the slow down is probably due to the cost of the blur + compositing. Did you try to "slow down" the view yourself with setPreferredFramesPerSecond:30 so that the view slow down but preserve a constant frame rate in that case (it might look better). Also is pausing the view an acceptable solution when a popover is presented?

Comment: Are you running in simulator?

Comment: I am using running on real iPad, I'll try setting the preferred frames today and will see. Pausing would not work in the current state, I would have to rethink some other stuff.

Comment: SceneKit (and Sprite Kit) have some horrendous bugs for overlays of any sort. This should, mostly, work fine, but it doesn't.

Comment: The [Placing Objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality) sample code from Apple uses transparent overlays with no drop in frame rate. Can you post your code?